# Cannot Bind Json to Object

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, postman

I am having an issue while trying the WebAPI of net core.

For some reason my object always comes empty no matter what I try. I've checked several other SO questions regarding this but cannot find a solution for what I am facing.

My model:

[image]

My controller (getting the null object):
[image]

And the POSTMAN request:
[image]

I've tried both with and without the [FromBody] option as I've seen in other SO questions that some people solved their issues with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: add `public` modifier before `Action` property, its not getting de-serialized by json.net, thereby making it `default(string)` which is `null`

Comment: It was as dumb as that... thank you @KunalMukherjee. Problem solved

Comment: @ADP_X, P.S do not add images, add code to the question always!

Comment: I'll do so @Div, thanks

Comment: It seems silly to ask since the answer was so simple, but @KunalMukherjee could you please add your comment as an answer? That way future visitors can see what the accepted answer was.

Comment: @JamieTaylor added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the auto-implemented properties must have an public modifier before them to for JSON.NET to safely deserialize them.

```
public class APIRequest
{
    string Action { get; set; }
}
```

Because in the above example no access modifier is given, thereby making it as private, so the default value of the property is assigned which is [`default(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions) that is `null`.

```
public class APIRequest
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

By default all class members are `private` and the class itself is `internal`, so you have to mark your property with public modifier.